# Regex to select only last word in string with consistent title

Tags: c#, regex

I am parsing the text body of an email and am looking for help with an expression that will target the last word of a string that follows a title.  The title will always be Member Name: but the string after this can vary.  I want to ignore everything but the last word, which will be the first name.

For exmaple:

Member Name: JAMES, MAJ LABRON would target LABRON
Member Name: BARKLEY, CHARLES would target CHARLES
Member Name: JORDAN, 1ST LT MICHAEL would target MICHAEL

Answer (score 2):

Regex solution:

```
var str = "JAMES, MAJ LABRON";
var rgx = new Regex(@"^.+ (\w+)$");
Console.WriteLine(rgx.IsMatch(str));
```

### Explanation:

> ^ - Start of string
>
> .+ - One or more characters
>
> \w+ - matches a single
>   word

**Note:**

Using `()` around `\w+` will group the matched word in case you need to use it in C# later on.

If you want a non-Regex solution, you can simply `string.Split()` the string and get the last word.

```
var last = str.Split(' ').Last();
```